# Box shadow for panel

Tags: css, box-shadow

I have following css property defined:

box-shadow: #CCCCCC x2 y2 blur2;

But, when I run on browser, it says invalid property / value. What's wrong here?

Comment: What are `x2`,`y2` and `blur2`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

replace `x2`, `y2`, `blur2` with actual values.

Check out this **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/shrinivas93/eye4nbkz/)**.

Here is the snippet

```css
div {
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  background: red;
  box-shadow: #CCCCCC 20px 30px 10px;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Please follow this image which has defined the shadow
[image]